# How to implement this in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, rest, authentication

I am new to nodejs and working on a proof of concept just for fun.

**Background**:
I have a cloud directory of user information (like username, password and other info). This cloud directory can be used to authenticate a user only via restful API (i.e. no direct connectivity using LDAP or JDBC etc.).

**Aim**:
To build an LDAP interface for this cloud directory. To start with I am interested only in authentication (LDAP bind).

**Intended Flow**:

1. LDAPClient initiates a standard LDAP simple BIND request:
   Host: host where my nodejs app will run
   Port: 1389 (port that my nodejs app will be bound to) 
   Username: a user from cloud directory
   Password: user's password
2. This request is received by my NodeJS app (I am using ldapjs module).

   ```
   // process ldap bind operation
   myLdapServer.bind(searchBase, function (bindReq, bindRes, next) {
     // bind creds
     var userDn = req.dn.toString();
     var userPw = req.credentials;
     console.log('bind DN: ' + req.dn.toString());
   ...
   ...
   }
   ```
3. Within the above callback, I must use http.request to fire a restful API (POST) to the cloud directory with the details I received from the BIND request (i.e. username, password).
4. If restful api response status is 200 (auth success), then I must return success to the LDAPClient, else I must return invalid credentials error.

Success:

```
    bindRes.end();
    return next();
```

Failure:

```
    Console.log("returning error");
    return next(new ldap.InvalidCredentialsError());
```

Questions:

Is this possible using NodeJS? Asking because of the nesting involved as evident above (calling of REST API from within a callback). Also since this is an authentication operation, this is meant to be a blocking operation(?)

Thanks,
Jatin

UPDATE:

Thanks Klvs, my solution is more or less like the one you posted. Please have a look at the snippet below:

```
    // do the POST call from within callback
    var postRequest = https.request(postOptions, function(postResponse) {
        console.log("statusCode: ", postResponse.statusCode);
        if(postResponse.statusCode!=200) {
            console.log("cloud authentication failed: "+postResponse.statusCode);
            return next(ldapModule.InvalidCredentialsError());
        } else {
            postResponse.on('data', function(d) {
                console.info('POST result:\n');
                process.stdout.write(d);
                console.info('\n\nPOST completed');
            });
            res.end();
            return next();
        }
    });

    // write json data
    postRequest.write(postData);
    postRequest.end();
    postRequest.on('error', function(e) {
        console.error("postRequest error occured: "+e);
    });
```

Successful authentication works fine, however, failed authentication does not send any response back to the LDAPClient at all. My client just times out instead of showing authentication failure error. I do see the "cloud authentication failed: " log message on the Node console, which means the below statement is not doing what I intend it do:

```
            return next(ldapModule.InvalidCredentialsError());
```

Note that the above statement works when I remove the rest call etc, and just return the error back to the client.

Am I missing something?

Thanks,
Jatin

Comment: Updated, see my comment on my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it's possible in nodejs. If I understand you want to make an authenticating request to a server and have it either fail or succeed.

```
const request = require('request')
// process ldap bind operation
myLdapServer.bind(searchBase, function (bindReq, bindRes, next) {
  // bind creds
  var userDn = req.dn.toString();
  var userPw = req.credentials;
  console.log('bind DN: ' + req.dn.toString());
  request.post({username: userDn, password: userPw}, (err, res, body)=>{
    if(err) {
      console.log("returning error");
      next(new ldap.InvalidCredentialsError());
    } else {
      bindRes.end();
      next();
    }
  })
}
```

Is that what you're looking for? If so, you just need to get accustom to callbacks.

Comment: Thanks klvs, can you please review the update to my question?

Comment: I'm not sure what framework you're using if any but I did notice that you're not sending a response if it doesn't authenticate. If it is sucessful you call `res.end()` but you don't do that if it fails. By not sending a response you'll cause it to time out as the client is waiting for one.

Comment: Thanks klvs, my bad
incorrect: 
return next(ldapModule.InvalidCredentialsError());
correct:
return next(new ldapModule.InvalidCredentialsError());

Comment: Now that it is working, I am wondering, how node is acting in a **synchronous** manner here? i.e. the ldap bind request is not responded to immediately. Instead, node appears to block it (_desirable in this case_) until it receives a response from the rest-api in the callback.

Comment: I believe you don't need to return either. next(), being a callback, is similar to a syncronous language's return. There are other control structures like Promises that can be used like callbacks in Javascript. Not all actions are async in javascript. It take some getting used to but generally call backs are where things get async. This is not explicitly true, but imagine that at a block level everything is syncronous. Take a look at this: https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-async-programming-in-node-js/

Comment: Thanks much klvs!